# How to dynamically update Dash chart / table on server side events (without dcc interval)?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I have a question and hope that you can help me.

We need to display data from a handheld measuring device in a Dash chart and table.
The device does not send data regularly but only when the user presses a button on it,
then we have to update the chart and table in the UI.

Of course we could create a API around the device and pull new data every second with dcc interval, but I would like to know if there are other possibilities.

Maybe have an open websocket connection to the device’s API and send new events on that.
But how would the connection to the Dash frontend look like?
Can someone point me into the right direction on this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to transmit the data via websocket, you could use the [`WebSocket`](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#websocket) component. If you only need to transmit data from the server to the client (i.e. not bidirectional communication), an alternative could be to use server sent events (SSE) via the [`EventSource`](https://github.com/thedirtyfew/dash-extensions#eventsource) component. Both components are available in [`dash-extensions`](https://pypi.org/project/dash-extensions/).

To illustrate the latter approach, here is a small Dash app that uses the `EventSource` component to update a graph when a SSE arrives,

```
from dash import Dash, html, Input, Output, dcc
from dash_extensions import EventSource

# The url of server that emits the events.
sse_url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
# Create small example app.
app = Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div([dcc.Graph(id="graph"), EventSource(id="sse", url=sse_url)])
# You could also use a normal callback, but client side callbacks yield better performance.
app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(val) {
        values = val ? JSON.parse(val) : []
        return {data: [{y: values , type: "scatter"}]}
    }
    """,
    Output("graph", "figure"),
    Input("sse", "message"),
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

While any type of server could be used to emit the SSEs, for completeness, here is a server implementation that emits random data in the format expected by the Dash app,

```
import asyncio
import random
import uvicorn
from sse_starlette.sse import EventSourceResponse
from starlette.applications import Starlette
from starlette.middleware import Middleware
from starlette.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = Starlette(middleware=[Middleware(CORSMiddleware, allow_origins=['*'])])

async def numbers():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        yield [random.randrange(200, 1000) for _ in range(10)]

@app.route("/")
async def sse(request):
    generator = numbers()
    return EventSourceResponse(generator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8000)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! Another small question, is there a way to update a Dash table with new data coming in via websocket value by value? Meaning add a new row if data is sent. Or do I have to gather the data on the server side and always send the complete table?

Comment: There is nothing special about the updates being performed via websockets (or SSEs for that matter) as compared to other property changes. Hence, the answer to your question depends on the implementation of  table component that you are using, and I would thus consider it off topic with respect to this question. That being said, to my knowledge, the default Dash data table does not supports append operations, i.e. you would have to send the complete table.